# Explaination of dd command in nasm

Tags: assembly, kernel, dd

I am reading osdev wiki. I came across these two lines of code.

```
 nasm kernel.asm -f bin -o kernel.bin
    dd if=kernel.bin of=/dev/fd0
```

I can understand the first line but I can't understand the second line. what the second line do? what is this dd command? what is this /dev/fd0 here? Can anybody explain me this please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dd` is a utility that allows you to copy a file. The `if` parameter stands for 'input file' and `of` is output file. The command here is copying the kernel.bin onto the /dev/fd0 device.

Answer (score 0):

It's just copying kernel.bin to a floppy disk (/dev/fd0).

[$ man dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)